# pymongo take a lot of time when I apply a for loop to get information

Tags: python, mongodb, for-loop, pymongo

I have a db in mongodb and I need to get all the observations that are in a list of ids (rut).

The form of the data in mongo is (JSON format):

```
{'rut': '451254', 'nombre': 'mario castillo', 'edad': '24',
'sexo': 'M', 'ciudad': 'Santiago'}
{'rut': '568418', 'nombre': 'antonio machuca', 'edad': '24',
'sexo': 'M', 'ciudad': 'Santiago'}
{'rut': '398768', 'nombre': 'catalina henriquez', 'edad': '24',
'sexo': 'F', 'ciudad': 'Santiago'}
```

while the rut list is a python list:

```
rut = ['568418', '398768']
```

So what I need is get the complete document (or observation (?)) that match the ids in the list, i.e.

```
# result 
{'rut': '568418', 'nombre': 'antonio machuca', 'edad': '24',
'sexo': 'M', 'ciudad': 'Santiago'}
{'rut': '398768', 'nombre': 'catalina henriquez', 'edad': '24',
'sexo': 'F', 'ciudad': 'Santiago'}
```

I have a code as follow:

```
client = MongoClient("mongodb://User:Pass@IP:port") 
db = client["EPI"]
lab = db["LAB"]

casos_lab = []
for x in tqdm.tqdm(ruts_buscar):
    for doc in lab.find({'rut': str(x)}):
        casos_lab.append(doc)
```

where rut_buscar is my "rut" or ids list

My problem is that it takes a lot of time for each iteration.

[image]

Someone knows how to speed up this code?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Edit, even newer answer (suggestion from below helped a lttile but not enough):

You could try to save all the `rut` values in a list before starting the loop, so for example `lab_rut = lab.find()['rut']` an then loop over that, maybe indexing into a list is quicker than indexing into a dict?
Also you could look up whether the `.append` method for lists is the fastest way of doing that or if there is something more efficient

Edit, new answer:

I am not familiar with what `tqdm` does and how it works, but if I understand correctly, your first for loop loops over your `rut` list. The second for loop loops over all documents in your collection, where the `rut` value matches the list entry.
This causes `lab.find` to be called as many times as the rut list has entries. Depending on the size of your collection I imagine this could take a lot of time.

If all of your documents in the lab collection have the 'rut' key, try

```
casos_lab = []
for doc in lab.find():
    for x in rut_buscar:
        if x == doc['rut']
            casos_lab.append(doc)
```

If every rut is unique, you could even use a `break` statement to stop the inner loop as soon as `rut` was found like so

```
casos_lab = []
for doc in lab.find():
    for x in rut_buscar:
        if x == doc['rut']
            casos_lab.append(doc)
            break
```

I'm sorry if this code does not support what `tqdm` does.

Old answer:

There is no key 'identificacion_paciente' in your data, try

```
  for doc in lab.find({'rut': str(x)}):
```

Comment: It was my bad, identificacion_paciente is the same as rut I forgot edit it before paste de chunk of code

Comment: Ah okay that makes sense. I'll try to edit my answer then

Comment: This speed up a bit the code, but still is too slow. I have millions observations in "rut" and millions observations in "lab". I'm running the code since one hour and it goes at the iteration 11.000

Comment: Ok I think I'm too inexperienced to be of much more help, I have never worked with code that took more than a few seconds to run :D
Just some ideas, I'll edit my post

Comment: You're welcome! Did you see the second edit I made? Did anything help?